# bulk create - what happens on errors

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If we use a mongoose model create method:

```
Model.create([{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: false}, {foo: 'star'}], (err, result) => {

    // should have an error, if foo is supposed to be a string

});
```

if there is an error when one of the documents is inserted, does that mean all the remaining documents fail? My guess is that all documents are attempted to be inserted, even if one fails, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `ordered: false` option, otherwise all inserts will fail if one fails:

```
Model.create([...], {ordered: false}, (err, result) => {
   // if one fails, other inserts may succeed
});
```

vs.

```
Model.create([...], {ordered: true}, (err, result) => {
    // if one fails, all inserts fail
});
```